# Update a chart dynamically with socket.io in real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, socket.io, chart.js

I have a basic node.js webserver. The connected clients can send values to the server. The server stores them in an array. The array will be send back to the client every 1/25 second and the client draws the chart with this array. So every client sees the updateted chart in real time. But unfortunately the clients do not draw the Chart.

What i tried:
The client emits an event and sends a value to the server. The server listenes to this event and stores the value in an array. With a setInterval the server emits the array every 1/25 second to the client. The client gets the array and draws the chart.

client.js:

```
var numbers = [];
var context = document.getElementById("chart");
var config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [
       {
       backgroundColor: ['orange', 'blue', 'yellow'],
       data: numbers,
       borderWidth: 0,           
       }
    ]
  },
  options: {
       responsive: false,
  }    
}
var chart = new Chart(context, config);

const socket = io();

var someValue = 7;

socket.emit('add', someValue);

socket.on('update', (arr) => {
    numbers = arr;
    console.log(numbers);
});
```

server.js:

```
const chartArray = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('add', (data) => {
        chartArray.push(data);
    }); 

    setInterval(function() {
        socket.emit('update', chartArray);
    },1000/25);
});
```

When i log the the numbers array in the console of the client it works. The server emits the array every 1/25 second to the client and the client gets the array. But the chart will not be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not updating the chart

```
chart.data.datasets.data = arr;
chart.update();
```

Comment: Oh man i knew it was something stupid that i forgot. Thank you very much.